# Injecting attributes into drawable resources files on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, attributes, android-drawable

I'm trying to find the best way to reuse resource files.  In this example, I'm trying to create a ghost button for Android.  I have a ghost button drawable xml file that defines the background, but I would like to be able to specify the color (specifically **without** using theme based defined colors).

ghost.xml:

```
  <shape
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:radius="@dimen/ghost_button_corner" />
  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
  <stroke android:width="@dimen/ghost_button_stroke_size" android:color="?attr/ghost_color" /></shape>
```

ghost_style.xml:

```
<!-- STYLABLE -->
<attr name="ghost_color" format="reference" />

<!-- STYLES -->
<style name="GhostButtonBlack" parent="@style/GhostButton">
    <item name="ghost_color">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="GhostButtonWhite" parent="@style/GhostButton">
    <item name="ghost_color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<!-- BASE -->
<style name="GhostButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/ghost_button_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/ghost_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ghost</item>
</style>
```

within layout.xml:

```
    <Button
    style="@style/GhostButtonWhite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="White Ghost Button" />
```

But I'm currently getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5 
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:425)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:987)
```

**NOTE**
I recognize this type of styling can be done via code.  My ideal solution would involve **no** code; just resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the GradientDrawable from your shape and apply a different color programmaticaly like this:

```
GradientDrawable mygrad = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();
color = inflater.getContext().getResources().getColor(yourcolorinstyles);
mygrad.setColor(color);
```

Comment: maybe you could try doing it as a selector with different states

Comment: you make a ghostbutton.xml   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blackbutton" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bluebutton" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normalbutton" />
</selector>

Comment: not sure how this solves the problem?  How would "blackbutton" / state_checked "false" get set via resources/styling?

Comment: sry for the delay. if you use a checkbox instead of a button it changes automaticaly from unchecked state to checked state. But I am not sure if it is possible to use more than one state.

Comment: I would like to create any number of GhostButton*Color* styles by simply defining the "ghost_color" attribute and letting that get passed into the ghost drawable that uses that attribute.  This is one small step within a rather large styling design I'm working on.  I'm looking for a non-hack solution.